# Angular 7 + SignalR: Cannot find namespace 'SignalR', because tsconfig.app.json is ignored

Tags: angular, signalr, tsconfig

In my Angular app(version 7), I'm using SignalR to setup the connection, based on the  solution I found online, I can set up the connection, it works.

The code is as following

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { StreamParams } from './signalr-connection.model';
declare let $: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRConnectionService {
  public connection: SignalR.Hub.Connection;   // SignalR namespace
  public proxy: SignalR.Hub.Proxy;  // SignalR namespace

  constructor(url: string, streamParams: StreamParams) {
    this.connection = $.hubConnection(url, {
      qs: streamParams
    });
  }

  public addHub(hubName: string): void {
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy(hubName);
  }

  public start(): void {
    this.connection.start({ jsonp: false })
      .done(() => { console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + this.connection.id); })
      .fail(() => { console.log('Could not connect.'); });
  }
}
```

I also installed the `@types/signalr`. In the `tsconfig.json` file I also set as following:

```
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"types": ["jquery", "signalr"]
```

In development mode of compilation, I got the below error:

[image]

It said that `Cannot find namespace 'SignalR'`. But It compiled successfully and the app can run as well. So what's the issue?

**Edit: I find the solution by myself, and provide it here for  information.**

It turns out angular-cli generated another TS config file, `tsconfig.app.json`, which is ignored by me.

Basically speaking, `tsconfig.json` provides the global basic setting. And `tsconfig.app.json` is for application level setting.

so I add `"types": ["signalr"]` to the `tsconfig.app.json` file, then error removes away.

Comment: This is so obvious, you are not importing SignalR anywhere "public connection: SignalR.Hub.Connection;   // SignalR namespace", for Angular to recognize any such definitions it should be imported or aliased then used

Comment: did u run ng build --aot, to confirm its compiling correctly?

Comment: Please check the updated post. I added the answer I find. @yanky_cranky

Comment: thx. had the same problem while running the jasmine unit tests. the type was declared in the tsconfig.app.json, but not in the tsconfig.spec.json